# R Logging display name of the script

Tags: r, logging, loginfo

this is an atomic example of my current issue:

For the moment I have a project containing several R scripts (all in the same directory named DIR). I have a main script in DIR sourcing all the R files and, containing a basicconfig:

```
basicConfig()
```

I take two scripts in DIR, dog.r and cat.r. I have currently only one function in these scripts. In dog.r :

```
feedDog <- function(){
    loginfo("The dog is happy to eat!", logger="dog.r")

}
```

And in cat.r :

```
feedCat <- function(){
     loginfo("The cat is voracious", logger="cat.r")
}
```

It's fine with this example. But in real I have something like 20 scripts and 20 possible error messages in each. So that instead of writting:

```
loginfo("some message", logger="name of script")
```

I would like to write:

```
loginfo("some message", logger=logger)
```

And configure different loggers.
The issue is that if I declare a logger in each R scripts, only one will be taken into account when I source all files with my main ... I dunno how to bypass this issue.

PS: in Python it is possible to define a logger in each file taking automatically the name of the script like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But I am afraid it is not possible in R ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `source()` a file, the functions created in that file will have an attribute called `srcref` that stored the location from the sourced file that the function came from. If you have a name that points to that function, you can use `getSrcFilename` to get the filename the function came from. For example, create a file that we can source

```
# -- testthis.R --

testthis <- function() {
    loginfo("Hello")
}
```

Now if we enter R, we can run

```
loginfo <-function(msg) {
    fnname <- sys.call(-1)[[1]]
    fnfile <- getSrcFilename(eval(fnname))
    paste(msg, "from", deparse(fnname), "in", fnfile)
}

source("testthis.R")

testthis()
# [1] "Hello from testthis in testthis.R"
```

The function `loginfo` uses `sys.call(-1)` to see what function it was called from. Then it extracts the name from that call (with `[[1]]`) and then we use `eval()` to turn that "name" object into the actual function. Once we have the function, we can get the source file name. This is the same as running

```
getSrcFilename(testthis)
```

if you already knew the name of the function. So it is possible, it's just a bit tricky. I believe this special attribute is only added to functions. Other than that, each source file doesn't get it's own namespace or anything so they can't each have their own logger.