# file from where function was sourced

Tags: r, debugging

When debugging a function, `R` displays the full filename from where the function was sourced. Example output shown below.

**Where is this information (filename) stored and is it user accessible?**

```
    > debugonce(myFunction)
    > myFunction(x)
    debugging in: myFunction(x)
    debug at /path/to/filename.r#41: {

        < body of myFunction >
    }
    Browse[2]> Q
    >
```

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546356/r-logging-display-name-of-the-script/24546885#24546885 and check out the `?getSrcFilename` function.

Comment: Interesting... it's an attribute on the attribute.  Thanks Señor Flick

Answer (score 0):

There are attributes on the attribute `srcref` of the function.   One of those is `srcfile`

```
 attr(attr(myFunc, "srcref"), "srcfile")

 or
 getSrcFilename(myFunc)
```

*Thanks to @MrFlick*